# bootstrap divider for responsive navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-design

I want to add horizontal divider on responsive navigation. This is bootstrap responsive view on mobile.

[image]

I want to add a divider in between the last two menu items namely "link" and "dropdown" menu items. If i add the following `<li class='divider></li>'`

in between them, it is not working. is there any other bootstrap way to do it? or we need to create our own classes to achieve this in responsive grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to write @media queries like below:
[See Divider in Browser- Resize browser to check](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/zqNzk/5/show/)
[JSFiddle with Divider in collapsible nav](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/zqNzk/6/)

[image: Screenshot of Browser with Divider]

```
 /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav > li.divider {
    *width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 1px;
   *margin: -5px 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #e5e5e5;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
     }
     }
 @media (min-width: 600px){
   .nav-collapse .nav > li.divider {
    *width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 1px;
   *margin: -5px 0 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #e5e5e5;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  }
  }
 /* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
   .nav-collapse .nav > li.divider {
   *width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   margin: 9px 1px;
  *margin: -5px 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not `<hr>` or `<legend></legend>`?

```
<li class = ""></li>
<li class = ""></li>
<div class = "visible-phone">
<legend></legend>
</div>
<li class = ""></li>
<li class = ""></li>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?